# Android how to cancel AlarmManager.setAlarmClock()

Tags: android, alarmmanager, android-alarms, android-5.0-lollipop

There is this [new AlarmManager.setAlarmClock(...) method](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/AlarmManager.html#setAlarmClock(android.app.AlarmManager.AlarmClockInfo,%20android.app.PendingIntent)) in API 21, which sets a new alarm and displays a status bar alarm icon.

I use it like this:

```
AlarmManager am = (AlarmManager) context.getSystemService(Context.ALARM_SERVICE);
Intent intent = new Intent(ALARM_ALERT_ACTION);
PendingIntent sender = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(context, 0, intent, PendingIntent.FLAG_CANCEL_CURRENT);
am.setAlarmClock(new AlarmManager.AlarmClockInfo(time, sender), sender);
```

The problem is that I don't know how to cancel this alarm, because this code doesn't work:

```
am.cancel(PendingIntent.getBroadcast(context, 0, new Intent(ALARM_ALERT_ACTION), PendingIntent.FLAG_CANCEL_CURRENT));
```

The alarm itself is cancelled (my BroadcastReceiver's onReceive is not called) but the status bar alarm icon is still displayed and also AlarmManager.getNextAlarmClock() returns this alarm.

Comment: Try removing `PendingIntent.FLAG_CANCEL_CURRENT` from your `cancel()` call.

Comment: @CommonsWare @Smuggler How can I remove `PendingIntent.FLAG_CANCEL_CURRENT`, it's not an optional parameter.

Comment: @AVEbrahimi: Replace it with `0`.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

`PendingIntent.FLAG_CANCEL_CURRENT` says "cancel the current `PendingIntent`". That confuses `AlarmManager` when you go to `cancel()` it, and a confused `AlarmManager` is never a good thing.

Only use `PendingIntent.FLAG_CANCEL_CURRENT` when you have a clear reason to do so. Don't use it as some default, "oh, I'll use this instead of `0`, because I like typing in lots of characters" value. :-)

Comment: Furthermore, using the same PendingIntent `sender` for both purposes is unlikely to work right. The `AlarmClockInfo` constructor's `showIntent` argument tells the OS what to do when the user taps on the alarm clock info in the notification drawer or the lock screen. `setAlarmClock()`'s `operation` argument tells AlarmManager what to do when the alarm "goes off." Presumably you should pass the latter to `cancel()`.

Comment: @CommonsWare, does `PendingIntent.FLAG_NO_CREATE` work this both `AlarmManager.AlarmClockInfo` and `setAlarmClock` ?

Comment: @Vyacheslav: `FLAG_NO_CREATE` does not really have anything to do with anything in `AlarmManager` specifically. I suggest that you ask a fresh Stack Overflow question where you explain exactly what your concern is.

Comment: @CommonsWare , I've already created it: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/36110837/check-if-charged-setalarmclock-of-alarmmanager