# check if charged setAlarmClock of AlarmManager

Tags: android, alarmmanager, android-5.0-lollipop

The Lollipop API represents `setAlarmClock` method to charge an intent.
to start in I can use this code:

```
am.setAlarmClock(new AlarmManager.AlarmClockInfo(nexttime,pi), pi);
```

to cancel:

```
am.cancel(PendingIntent.getService(ctx, 0, intentS, 0));
```

but how to check whether it was already charged?

In common case I can use this:

```
boolean alarmUp = (PendingIntent.getBroadcast(ctx, 0, intent, PendingIntent.FLAG_NO_CREATE) != null);
```

but what about this new method? Does it works properly for `setAlarmClock` on pure `set` method?

Comment: What do you mean by "charge an intent"? Note: You're supposed to pass different Intents with different purposes to `new AlarmClockInfo` and `setAlarmClock`. The first Intent opens the UI to edit the alarm. The alarm time triggers the second Intent.

Comment: I need to know whether I used `setAlarmClock` or not.

Comment: Are you asking whether you *should* use `setAlarmClock` or not? Use it when you (1) need to set an alarm that the user can see, (2) need the alarm to trigger on time, even in Doze mode. `setAlarmClock` will show an alarm clock icon on the right side of the notification bar. It will also show an alarm clock icon in the pull-down notification, along with the target alarm time. If the user taps that icon, Android will run the `AlarmClockInfo` intent.

Comment: @Jerry101 , I have to check this programmatically. Not visual information.